# Delegate address cannot send transaction

Tags: transactions

My entrusted address suddenly can't send the transaction, display the check input, there is no problem in the past, there are a lot of balances in the address, just send a small part, I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: you really need to add more details about things you have tried(such as commands you used to do the things you described or what wallet do you use? or how much balance you are trying to transfer). The way it's written, I doubt anybody can really help you and answer properly.

Comment: I can send it normally in the morning, I can't send it in the afternoon, I can't send it normally the next day, I didn't do anything, it used to be normal

Comment: Hi, welcome to tezos stack exchange! your question needs to be clarified and specific. We don't know anything about your setup, how you try to send the xtz, what is the error message you encounter etc... basically just try to put yourself in our shoes, we need concrete details to assess what is going on.